# Trying to delete product from my list using pointer and struct

Tags: arrays, c, loops, undefined-behavior, memmove

In this function, I trying to delete a product from a list. Visual Studio shows me a red line under

```
list->itemList[i].productName = list->itemList[i + 1].productName;
```

and

```
list->itemList[i].unit = list->itemList[i + 1].unit;
```

but not under

```
list->itemList[i].amount = list->itemList[i + 1].amount;
```

The `productName` and `unit` is `char`, and the `amount` is `float`.

```
void removeItem(struct ShoppingList *list){
    int itemToDelet;
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list->length; i++) {
            printf("%d. %s \t %.2f \t %s\n", i + 1, list->itemList[i].productName, list->itemList[i].amount, list->itemList[i].unit);
        }
        printf("\n\nWhich product do you want to remove? ");
        scanf("%d", &itemToDelet);
        if (itemToDelet <= list->length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list->length; i++) {
                if (itemToDelet == i + 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list->length; i++) {
                        list->itemList[i].productName = list->itemList[i + 1].productName;
                        list->itemList[i].amount = list->itemList[i + 1].amount;
                        list->itemList[i].unit = list->itemList[i + 1].unit;
                        list->length--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nThe list contains only %d items!", list->length);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `struct ShoppingList`? Please add that code to your posted question.

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the squiggle it should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @LeoParden The function in any case is wrong and invokes undefined behavior. The loops within the function do not make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the contents of a string (e.g. type `char[10]`), use `strcpy`. Arrays of characters cannot be assigned, just copied.

```
strcpy(list->itemList[i].productName,list->itemList[i + 1].productName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data members `productName` and `unit` are character arrays and arrays do not have the assignment operator.

To copy strings stored in character arrays you should use the standard C function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>` as for example

```
strcpy( list->itemList[i].productName, list->itemList[i + 1].productName );
```

But in any case your function is incorrect and invokes undefined behavior. The for loops within the function do not make a sense.

Instead of the for loops you could use another standard C function `memmove` declared in the same header `<string.h>` as for example

```
memmove( list->itemList + itemToDelet - 1, 
         list->itemList + itemToDelet,
         ( list->length - itemToDelet ) * sizeof( *list->itemList ) );

--list->length;
```

Also before the call of `memmove` you need to check that the value of `itemToDelet` is greater than `0`.